# ngrok doesn't run wiith admin privileges

Tags: ngrok, tunnel, localtunnel

I can not install Ngrok as a service on Windows.

The prompt say "install failed" when we have run ngrok with admin privilieges.

In my ngrok dashboard said that tunnel was initialized but the edge show ERR_NGROK_8012.

I change the tunnel yet but it doesn't work.